# Disable stylesheet based on referrer

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, hotlinking

I don't want to allow the stylesheet (hosted with me) to be loaded on a couple of domains.

This is what I'm trying, but doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://example1.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.css$ http://www.mywebsite.com/dummy.css [R,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://example2.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.css$ http://www.mywebsite.com/dummy.css [R,L]
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: You can't. The referrer header in a http request can be spoofed like any other detail of a request. Therefore it is not suitable for protection.

Comment: Thats alright cause eBay won't spoof it .. someone is using it on their ebay listing.

Comment: How are you testing this? Are you looking at the HTTP headers you are sending and receiving when you make the request? (Stylesheets are usually cached).

Comment: And even if not: you cannot protect a set of style sheets. The moment you prevent it the person will simply copy it once and that's it. It is not worth the effort, since no harm is done.

Comment: I want to allow `all` except say `x` and `y`. So for those, I want to load a different stylesheet.

Comment: @arkascha you're not getting it, its alright if someone copies it, can't do much about it, but hotlinking is not right, thats what I want to manage.

Comment: I did very well understand what you are trying to do. I just said it is not worth it, since no harm is done. You confirmed that with your comment...

Comment: @arkascha — It can munch bandwidth.

Comment: @Quentin Someone is hosting web stuff and you are concerned about some stupid css file's size adding up to eat the bandwidth? OK...

Comment: Someone is copying my stuff AND hotlinking to it directly, its not about bandwidth or anything so I don't understand your argument, my question simply is how to load another file based on referrer. He may copy it or do whatever, but I won't let him have it free and easy.

Comment: I am on the side of arkascha, but if you just want to block it do this: 
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} google\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css/**.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect requests to load.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.css$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* load.php
```

css/**load.php**

```
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 

if (strpos($referrer, 'allowedwebsite1.com') !== false or 
    strpos($referrer, 'allowedwebsite2.com') !== false ) {

    header("Content-type: text/css", true);
    $css = file_get_contents("style.css");
    echo $css;
} 
else {
    header("Content-type: text/css", true);
    echo ''; // empty stylesheet
}
```